# How to retrieve fields along with aggregate function in elasticsearch 5.1 (using curl)?

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

For Example in sql 
select count(*),x,y from abc group by x,y

I want the same thing in curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregations for that, like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/abc -d '{
  "_source": ["x", "y"],
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_x" : {
      "terms": {
        "field": "x"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_y": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "y"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: `"aggs": {
    "count": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "DestinationIP.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_x": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sourceIP.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_by_y": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "sourcePORT.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } `    Group by is working properly but with count its throwing an error

Comment: The `count(*)` aggregate is per `x`and per `y`, so that's what you get with my query

Comment: what if its min or max or sum ?

Comment: If it's min or max, then you need another sub-aggregation